# How to correctly return result of matrixes multiplication

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

I got a class for boolean matrix.
Deallocating memory in destructor does not work correctly, it tries to delete invalid pointers - as I noticed, that happens when I try to multiply.

In operator* I return local object as a result and that part causes invalid pointers - so program crashes when deleting in destructor - the question is why that happens on this code ? and how to return result properly ?
Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;    
class BoolMatrix
{
    private:    
        bool ** items;  

    public:     
        size_t rows, cols;
        BoolMatrix(size_t = 0, size_t = 0);
        ~BoolMatrix();

        BoolMatrix operator * (const BoolMatrix &) const;
        //some other members
};    

BoolMatrix::BoolMatrix(size_t r, size_t c) : rows(r), cols(c)
{
    items = new bool*[r];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        items[i] = new bool[c];
        for (size_t j = 0; j < c; j++)
            items[i][j] = 0;        
    }
}    

BoolMatrix::~BoolMatrix()
{
    if (items)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {       
            if (items[i])
                delete[] items[i];
            items[i] = NULL;
        }   

        delete[] items;
        items = NULL;
    }
}    

BoolMatrix BoolMatrix::operator * (const BoolMatrix& that) const
{   
    //NxM * MxK = NxK
    if (cols != that.rows)
        return NULL;   

    Matrix res(rows, that.cols);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < that.cols; j++)
            for (size_t l = 0; l < that.rows; l++)
                res.items[i][j] = (res.items[i][j] + items[i][l]*that.items[l][j]) != 0;
    }

    return res;
}  

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    size_t n;
    cin >> n;
    BoolMatrix a(n, n);
    //matrix reading code
    a*a;    
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not use vectors?

Answer (score 0):

overload '=' operator and use it like a=a*a ; and destructor must be

```
BoolMatrix::~BoolMatrix()
{

        for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {       

            delete [] items[i];
        }   

        delete[] items;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

overload the copy constructor to copy whole array, so when function deletes it's local instance of class, it will delete it's own matrix, while function in main will have it's copy of matrix (note that if you leave it like this, what u get as result of function and variable from main which you equal in main to the result of function, point to exact same memory, that's why u need copy constructor)

Comment: yeah exactly, I forgot that I use pointers so they will be shared, I think using bool vector as a stack will be another solution as well. thanks

Comment: yeah, I just used bool vector on a stack but not in heap

Comment: Tried to write copy constructor but coudn't think of any correct copy constructor to fix the problem with invalid pointers

Comment: `BoolMatrix::BoolMatrix(other &t) 
{
    rows = t.rows;
    cols = t.cols
    items = new bool*[rows];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        items[i] = new bool[cols];
        for (size_t j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            items[i][j] = t[i][j];        
    }
}`
this would be right way

Answer (score 0):

I think that what happens is that you are trying to delete[] memory on the stack.

Instead of

```
Matrix res(rows, that.cols);
```

try with

```
Matrix res=new Matrix(rows, that.cols);
```